# Find contents of SQUARE brackets, excluding the brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

Find the following that start with UPPERCASE letter:

```
[Ki-Woo]
[Roger]
[Woman 1]
[Dr. Freeman]
[Dr. West]
[Anne Marie O'Donnell]
[Anne-Marie O'Donnell]
[Gary Wells]
[Gary L. Wells]
[R. H. Brown]
[Roger H. Brown]
[J. Edgar Hover]
```

Exclude/ignore the ones starting with lowercase letter:

```
[young Ashley]
[reporter 1]
[woman 1]
```

Here's what I currently have which finds ALL of them:

Find:    `\[([A-Z]*(?:(?:.*|\h*)[A-Z0-9][a-z]*)*)\]`

Replace: `$1\:`

EDIT: [Demo:](https://regex101.com/r/XR1zD1/1)

Thank You in Advance,
Hank

Comment: Would like to Find the lowercase in a SECOND expression which would have a SPACE (\h) after the closing ] bracket and followed by misc text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would already match your requirements:

```
\[([A-Z].*?)\]
```

The second expression that was asked for in the comment:

```
\[([a-z].*?)\]\h.*
```

Both in one expression (but with different capture groups...):

```
\[(?:([A-Z].*?)\]|([a-z].*?)\]\h.*)
```

Comment: The third expression is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank You SO MUCH !!